# Как удалить строку в таблице если там нет числа?

Tags: php

Приветствую, столкнулся с такой задачей, я с php недавно начал работать, и у меня эта задача вызвала трудности.

В общем есть таблица, она заполняется числами, если хоть в одной ячейки есть число то мы оставляем рядок. Если рядок полностью пустой то удалить его вообще, то есть не выводить данную строку в таблице

Для наглядности картинка:

[image: картинка]

Как можно реализовать данную функцию?

Comment: выводите из индексного массива циклом foreach?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin просто через for

Comment: покажите исходный массив

Comment: Телепаты разбежались... Код где?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cols = 7;
$arr = [
    ["1","2","3"],
    [],
]; 

echo '<table>';
foreach( $arr as $el ) {
    echo '<tr>';
        if($el) {
            for($i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++) {
                if($el && $i < count($el)) {
                    echo '<td>' . $el[$i] . '</td>';
                }else {
                    echo '<td></td>';
                }
            }
        }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

[пример](http://jdoodle.com/a/jAh)

Answer (score 1):

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5e60893451f8f1ccc262319e5dc9b185823d7655)

```
<?php
function getMaxArrayCount($array)
{
    $maxCount = 0;
    foreach ($array as $innerArray)
    {
        $arrayCount = count($innerArray);
        if($arrayCount > $maxCount)
        {
           $maxCount = count($innerArray); 
        }
    }
    return $maxCount;
}
?>

<table>
<?php

$myArray = 
    [
        ["one", "two", "three"], 
        ["test"]
    ];

foreach ($myArray as $innerArray)
{
    $innerCount = count($innerArray);
    if ($innerCount > 0)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        for($j = 0; $j < $innerCount; $j++)
        {
            echo "<td>". $innerArray[$j] ."</td>";
        }
        for($k = 0; $k < getMaxArrayCount($myArray) - $innerCount; $k++)
        {
            echo "<td></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
} 
?>

</table>
```